# How to copy parts of an 2d array?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript in google app script and I'm super confused why there is no simple way to copy stuff by value. I just want a simple way to copy a part of my matrix values2 into the new matrix matrix1. Why is that not possible?

```
var temp = []; 
for (var t = 0; t<9;t++) {temp[t]= 0;}; //[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var matrix1 = [];
for (var x = 0; x<20;x++) {matrix1[x]=temp;};
for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 9 ; y++) {
    matrix1[x][y] = values2[x+1][y+1];
}};
```

The code above fills the matrix with identical (last) lines.

Comment: How about `Array#slice`

Comment: `matrix1[x][y] = values2[x+1][y+1];` Where did you declare `values2`?

Comment: FWIW, `Array(10).fill(0)` to produce `[0,0,0,..]`. Combine that technique with an `Array.map` to create a bunch of arrays of arrays with very little code...

Answer (score 0):

Passing array as reference is common among programming languages. In this case, you don't even need `temp`:

```
var matrix1 = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
  matrix1[x] = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
    matrix1[x][y] = values2[x + 1][y + 1];
  }
};
```